# Plot one predictor and its quadratic term versus response variable (GLM binomial distribution)

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization, generalized-linear-model, marginal-distribution

I have the following model with four independent variables:

```
Model_A <- glm(GRSP~ppt+tem+density+land+I(land^2), family=binomial())
```

When I plot the variable `land` and its quadratic term versus the response variable I obtained a curve that do not fit my data. Could someone tell me if I am doing something wrong when creating the plot?

In order to create the plot, I first run the model with all variables centered and then used the coefficients of both `land` and `I(land^2)`.

```
y <- function(x) (1/(1+exp(-(3.7+0.03*(x-36.45)-0.01*(x-36.45)*(x-36.45)))))
x <- seq(0,100,5)
plot(x, y(x), type="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0,1), xlim=c(0,100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the parameters from your model fit (and your model fit is appropriate), then what you are doing should be fine.  The thing to bear in mind is that you are displaying a marginal projection of your data and your predicted values.  This means that you now have omitted variables, and if the omitted variables are at all correlated with the displayed variable (i.e., `land`), then it will look 'off'.

Comment: I have to run now, but I can try to add an example later, if that would help.